# ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.appcompat:design:1.1.0

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, androidx, material-components-android

when i implementation `'androidx.appcompat:design:1.1.0'` code in build gradle(module app)
it says `ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.appcompat:design:1.1.0`

i have try to change the implementation `'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'`
in appscompact  version it again shows error

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.bottomnavigation"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:design:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

> ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.appcompat:design:1.1.0
>   Show in Project Structure dialog
>   Affected Modules: app

Comment: androidx.appcompat:design:1.1.0 doesn't exist

Answer (score 4):

To you `Design Support Library` for `androidx` you need to use

Use this

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

Instead of

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:design:1.1.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

The library `androidx.appcompat:design` **doesn't exist**.

Check the [artifact mapping](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings):

```
com.android.support:design  ->  com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0
```

You can find [here the documentation](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) of the Material components library.

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate error,

Instead of this:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:design:1.1.0'
```

Write this:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
```